# Plotting interval of data in dataframe

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

A bit new to python so maybe code could be improved.

I have a txt file with x and y values, separated by some NaN in between.

Data goes from -x to x and then comes back (x to -x) but with somewhat different values of y, say:

`x=np.array([-0.02,-0.01,0,0.01,0.02,NaN,1,NaN,0.02,0.01,0,-0.01,-0.02])`

And I would like to plot (matplotlib) up to the first NaN with certain format, x=1 with other format, and last set of data with a third different format (color, marker, linewidth...).

Of course the data I have is a bit more complex, but I guess is a simple useful approximation.

Any idea?
I'm using pandas as my data manipulation tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a group label taking the `cumsum` of where x is null. Then you can define a dictionary keyed by the label with values being a dictionary containing all of the plotting parameters. Use `groupby` to plot each group separately, unpacking all the parameters to set the arguments for that group.

#### Sample Data

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.array([-0.02,-0.01,0,0.01,0.02,np.NaN,1,np.NaN,0.02,0.01,0,-0.01,-0.02])
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x})
```

#### Code

```
df['label'] = df.x.isnull().cumsum().where(df.x.notnull())

plot_params = {0: {'lw': 2, 'color': 'red', 'marker': 'o'},
               1: {'lw': 6, 'color': 'black', 'marker': 's'},
               2: {'lw': 9, 'color': 'blue', 'marker': 'x'}}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
for label, gp in df.groupby('label'):
    gp.plot(y='x', **plot_params[label], ax=ax, legend=None)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

This is what `df` looks like for reference after defining the group label

```
print(df)
       x  label
0  -0.02    0.0
1  -0.01    0.0
2   0.00    0.0
3   0.01    0.0
4   0.02    0.0
5    NaN    NaN
6   1.00    1.0
7    NaN    NaN
8   0.02    2.0
9   0.01    2.0
10  0.00    2.0
11 -0.01    2.0
12 -0.02    2.0
```

Comment: Nice solution, makes sense, adding this new label for each set of values. I ended up selecting

`df[df["label"]==0.0].x
df[df["label"]==1.0].x`
... etc
For it to make sense with the rest of my previous coding